# error trying to ansible with become machinectl

Tags: ansible, systemd

I've tried to make work some automation with ansible inside a systemd-nspawn container with machinectl commands.

I've found a become machinectl ansible plugin that seems to fit, but there's something I'm doing wrong because it's not working (or at least not working as I expect it should).

I'm running a playbook:

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/machinectl_test.yml -i inventory/imagecreators --user ansibleuser
```

The inventory file is just one machine:

```
[Fedora]
fedoraimagecreator
```

The playbook machinectl_test.yml:

```
- name: create machinectl user
  hosts: "*"
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: create machinectl user
      ansible.builtin.user:
        name: test
      become: yes
      become_method: machinectl
      become_flags: "--machine fedora36custom"
```

The user ansibleuser is inside sudoers with all elevations:

```
ansibleuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

And also inside wheel group:

```
root@fedoraimagecreator:~ # groups ansibleuser
ansibleuser : ansibleuser wheel
```

I've add a polkit ruleset that is part of the ansible documentation (and that is why ansible user is part of wheel, otherwise not needed, I think):

```
# A polkit rule needed to use the module with a non-root user.
# See the Notes section for details.
60-machinectl-fast-user-auth.rules: |
    polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
        if(action.id == "org.freedesktop.machine1.host-shell" && subject.isInGroup("wheel")) {
            return polkit.Result.AUTH_SELF_KEEP;
        }
    });
```

With all this. When I launch the playbook, this is the result:

```
root@ansible:~/ansible # ansible-playbook playbooks/machinectl_test.yml -i inventory/imagecreators --user ansibleuser

PLAY [create machinectl user] ******************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************
ok: [fedoraimagecreator]

TASK [create machinectl user] ******************************************************************************************
fatal: [fedoraimagecreator]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to fedoraimagecreator closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "\u001b[0;1;31mFailed to connect to bus: El `host' no está operativo\u001b[0m\r\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************
fedoraimagecreator         : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Regards.